# Swift : Share text through Twitter

Tags: xcode, swift, twitter, sharing

So basically I am making an event app. Everything has been going smoothly but there's just sharing the event to twitter.

I have searched the internet but all I am getting is using the native app of twitter which I don't want. I want to use the browser to tweet.

I have implemented this method for FB sharing.

Any idea would help me a lot.

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

    content.contentURL=NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com")
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com")

    content.contentTitle = "Shou 3emlin test app "
    content.contentDescription = "testing testing testing"

    let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    shareDialog.fromViewController = self
    shareDialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogMode.Browser
    shareDialog.shareContent = content


    if !shareDialog.canShow() {
        shareDialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogMode.Native
        shareDialog.shareContent = content
    }

    if shareDialog.canShow() {
        shareDialog.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put this in an action method of a button or in the method where you want to use the browser to tweet your text **Swift 3.0**:

```
let tweetText = "your text"
let tweetUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

let shareString = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=\(tweetText)&url=\(tweetUrl)"

// encode a space to %20 for example
let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

// cast to an url
let url = URL(string: escapedShareString)

// open in safari
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Found that Twitter app will be opened instead of Safari in case user has it installed, which is even better, because it looks more native. Thanks.

Comment: No twitter app is not opening@Vitalii

Answer (score 5):

@ronatory's solution worked like charm. It also opens a Twitter application if it's already installed on the user's device.

For swift 5+ use `UIApplication.shared.open(url!)` instead of `UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)` as it's deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/compose-tweets.html). This SDK allows you to compose tweets directly from your app.

```
let composer = TWTRComposer()

composer.setText("just setting up my Fabric")
composer.setImage(UIImage(named: "fabric"))

// Called from a UIViewController
composer.showFromViewController(self) { result in
    if (result == TWTRComposerResult.Cancelled) {
         print("Tweet composition cancelled")
    }
    else {
       print("Sending tweet!")
    }
}
```

Comment: As of today the Twitter Kit is going to be discontinued soon. Probably better to not choose it and look at other options instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
let tweetText = "hy" 
let tweetUrl = "http://rimmi/" 

let shareString = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=\(tweetText)&url=\(tweetUrl)"

// encode a space to %20 for example 
let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

// cast to an url 
let url = URL(string: escapedShareString)

// open in safari 
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In SwiftUI Swift5** use

```
Button {
    let tweetText = "Text for share"
    let shareString = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=\(tweetText)"
    let escapedShareString = shareString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    let url = URL(string: escapedShareString)
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
} label: {
    Text("Share on Twitter")
}
```