# Open a users twitter profile page from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am trying to deep link from my app to a user's twitter profile on the native twitter app. I have added schema rules for twitter and the following code:

```
    application.open(  URL(string:"twitter://user?screen_name=BarackObama", options[:],  completionHandler:{(success) in 
        print("Success")
    })
```

I can successfully open the twitter app and see the console print "Success" but my own twitter feed is what I see, not the user's twitter page. Is this url schema still valid?

Thanks

Comment: Tried it on iOS 10.3.2 with the latest version of Twitter app(7.0) and I was able to successfully open Obama's page with the URL you mentioned. Seems fine.

Answer (score 29):

OK, there are two easy steps to achieve this in Swift 4:

First, you have to modify Info.plist to list instagram and facebook with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Simply open Info.plist as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
</array>
```

After that, you can open twitter apps. Here is a complete code for twitter  you can link this code to any button you have as an Action:

```
@IBAction func followOnTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
   let screenName =  "AffordIt_App"
   let appURL = NSURL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=\(screenName)")!
   let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(screenName)")!

   let application = UIApplication.shared

   if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        application.open(appURL as URL)
   } else {
        application.open(webURL as URL)
   }
}
```

Comment: Any idea about sharing tweets?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809342/swift-share-text-through-twitter

Answer (score 11):

**Use this for twitter profile share, Swift 4:**

```
    let screenName =  "NJMINISTRIESINC"
    let appURL = URL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=\(screenName)")!
    let webURL = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(screenName)")!
    
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL)
        }
    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Twitter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(webURL)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but change the comment from Instagram to Twitter :)