# How to share a post from my app to twitter iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, share, slcomposeviewcontroller, twitterkit

I basically want the user to share something from my app to twitter. I was exploring the different methods possible and found SLComposeViewController but it is deprecated. Support for twitterKit has also been officially stopped by twitter. One possible way to do so seems to be like given in the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729998/open-a-users-twitter-profile-page-from-ios-app). Is there some other better way to do so? I would prefer if the user stays in the app itself (something similar to sharesheet for fb). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [twitter-kit-ios](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios).

For posting a tweet sample code from [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Compose-Tweets) would be following

**Objective-c**

```objectivec
// Objective-C
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];

[composer setText:@"just setting up my Twitter Kit"];
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterkit"]];

// Called from a UIViewController
[composer showFromViewController:self completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
    if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
    }
}];
```

**Swift**

```swift
// Swift
let composer = TWTRComposer()
    
composer.setText("just setting up my Twitter Kit")
composer.setImage(UIImage(named: "twitterkit"))
    
// Called from a UIViewController
composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result in
    if (result == .done) {
        print("Successfully composed Tweet")
    } else {
        print("Cancelled composing")
    }
}
```

Straight from the discontinuing blog post you can use, new api [endpoints](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/tweets).

Comment: Actually I was looking for an alternative to twitter-kit-ios since twitter has stopped support for it and so I would prefer not to use it!

Comment: Thanks for the time. I ended up using openurl finally since for standard api, user authentication would have been needed from the app and i didn't want user to login via twitter on the app.

Comment: @PriyanshuGoyal which endpoint you have used for sharing a link via App.

Comment: Can you also include the code in Objective-C?

Comment: Anything else twitter-kit-ios is now deprecated.